# ACL works in playground?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Could you please let us know if ACL works in playground ??

I want to create a rules, where owner of the asset can only modify the rules. I tried in playground by,which is not working

I created file as an asset and supplier as the owner of the asset. Then, created asset called file1 attached the supplier1 as the owner. When i am performing the submit transactions, Supplier2 can also modify the transactions. IS my rule are not valid ?? Do i need to some more ruless ??

```
     /**
     * New model file
     */

    namespace org.acme.model

    enum TransactionState {
      o CREATED
      o VERIFIED
     }

    asset File identified by fileId {
      o String fileId
      o String data
      --> Supplier owner
      o TransactionState state
    }

    participant Supplier identified by supplierId {
      o String supplierId
      o String emailId
      o String details
    }



    transaction DataValidate {
      --> File asset
      o TransactionState state
      --> Supplier supplier
    }   

/**
 * Data Validation by Supplier
 * @param {org.acme.model.DataValidate} dataValidate - the DataValidate transaction
 * @transaction
 */
function DataValidate(dataValidate) {
    dataValidate.asset.state = dataValidate.state;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.model.File')
      .then(function (assetRegistry) {
          return assetRegistry.update(dataValidate.asset);
      });
}


rule Rule1 {
    description: "can perform ALL operations , IF the participant is owner of the asset"
    participant(m): "org.acme.model.Supplier"
    operation: ALL
    resource(v): "org.acme.model.File"
    condition: (v.owner.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}


rule Member {
    description: "Allow the member read access"
    participant: "org.acme.model.Supplier"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.acme.model.*"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

My criteria, data validation should be done only by the owner of the file, not others. how to handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your main question - Yes the ACL file does work in the Online Playground, I have it working for one of my applications. If you are not referring to the online playground I'm not sure if the rest of my answer helps.

If you are using the online Playground presume that you've gone to the top right where it says 'admin' and created new identities and issued those to participants? If not you can do so by:

1. Clicking 'admin' in the top right of the playground
2. '+ Issue New ID'
3. Supply a User ID (whatever you like) and participant (will be one you created earlier) and then press 'Create New'
4. Select Option 2: '+ Add to my Wallet' (This will allow you to then use the identity and you will 'be' that participant

The reason I ask is that even with your ACL file working, if you remain as the 'admin' identity you can still view/do everything you want.

Another thing, could you try '===' instead of '==' in your Rule1? The two rules make sense, and from looking at it, all users can view, but an error would be raised if anyone except the owner tries to validate that asset because it requires UPDATE permissions which are not granted.

Hope this helps.